# Why the results on TwitterAPI differs from real search results

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to TwitterAPI and doing some experiences with that. I just found out that the API results differ from the real search results. Isn't there anyway to get same results via API as Twitter's real search results? Why Twitter hides some tweets in its API result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some situations that can cause this difference:

1. the Tweet you expected to see is from a protected account
2. because the data endpoint accounts for all compliance events
   (meaning that deleted Tweets, scrubbed geos, etc. will not be
   included in the response).
3. There is a known difference between results provided by the counts
   endpoint and the data endpoint. You may see a discrepancy in your
   results because the counts endpoint is pre-compliance (meaning that
   it does not account for things like deleted Tweets, scrub geo, etc.)
   whereas the data endpoint is compliant at the time of delivery and
   accounts for all compliance events.

For more details see: [DOCS](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/faq)